# How to change the case of only the URL to lowercase in href

Tags: urls

I am making my resume using `LaTeX.`

I have a section which capitalises its contents.

```
runsubsection{\href{my_url}{some_text}}
```

This will result in something like this:

```
SOME_TEXT
```

However, the url to which this text redirects results in a 404 error as it doesn't exist. The reason being the capitalization of the `my_url` in the section renders it useless.

I tried using this:

```
runsubsection{\href{\MakeLowercase{my_url}}{some_text}}
```

But this gives a compilation error.

How do I make this work?

EDIT:

Here is the definition of `runsubsection`:

```
\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Bol}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}
```

Comment: Where is `\runsubsection` from? Please provide a compilable document, not just fragmented code lines

Comment: I think it is defined here: https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/blob/master/OpenFonts/deedy-resume-openfont.cls#L69

Comment: Please place the code here. I'm not willing to follow external links

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have edited the question

Comment: It's still a fragment only,  with font specs to a font not available (to many, I suppose), but what do you think `\uppercase{#1}` does there ;-) ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This was the reason why I had commented with an external link to the entire repository

Comment: Basically, are you expecting the readers of this posting to go off on a code scavenger hunt to find out what various code fragments may mean? Shouldn't *you* be in charge of providing these explanations?

Comment: You should make sure not to capitalize the url in the first place, instead of lowercasing it as an afterthought. The server of the url may be configured to be case sensitive, and if that is the case lowercasing may make the url stop working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a year old now so you likely gave up or found an answer. For the people like me who later go searching for why this is happening, this fixes it.

```
\href{http://somelink.com/some_text}
{\runsubsection{Your Title}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following workaround with `\lowercase` (not `\Makelowercase`) might work:

```
\lowercase{\href{my_url}}{Some text}
```